# Does subprocess.call run even when the function it is in is not called

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am just practicing with the below code. When I run the code it seems to run the superman function even when I input another key.

```
Python3 dice.py
Select a number 1-5: 1
__pycache__ fizbuzz.py  q2.py       q4.py
dice.py     q1.py       q3.py       q5.py
I AM BATMAN
```

it executes subprocess.call('ls', shell=True) even when I input 1, which should only run the Batman function. this happens for every input. I get the correct answer but subprocess always procedes it? does subprocess run even when it's function is not called?

```
import subprocess

def batman():
    slogan = "I AM BATMAN"
    return slogan

def superman():
    subprocess.call('ls', shell=True)
    return "Success!"

def dice():
    user_choice = int(input("Select a number 1-5: "))
    outcomes = {
    1: batman(),
    2: superman(),
    3: "Wonder Woman",
    4: "The Flash",
    5: "Green Lantern"
    }
    answer = outcomes.get(user_choice, "Not a valid input")
    return answer
print(dice())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, **both** superman and batman get called no matter who is selected! To check add a `print('hello')` at the start of batman.

Why?

Well, once the application enters the function dice, it defines

```
outcomes = {
1: batman(),   #Function call!
2: superman(), #Function call!
3: "Wonder Woman",
4: "The Flash",
5: "Green Lantern"
}
```

as soon as we define outcomes, we make function calls - when defining `1:` we call `batman()` as evident by the parenthesis, same for `2:` - the function is evaluated (so it does run `ls`), and its result is stores (`'Success!'`). The problem is not in subprocess, it is in the app design. Option

1. Make sure all functions used here return strings - and then the string will be stored as the outcome (or just that they do not have unwanted consequences, though, why call superman if he is not needed?)
2. Decide that all outcomes are functions, and hold off on calling them.

example:

```
def dice():
    user_choice = int(input("Select a number 1-5: "))
    outcomes = {
    1: batman,
    2: superman,
    3: lambda: "With our powers combined,  Captain Planet!"
    }
answer = outcomes.get(user_choice, lambda: "Not a valid input") #Note the default is a function now as well returning the string.
return answer() #Call here.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i tried it and it works. I didnt realize that it was calling the functions.

Comment: this is correct as long as everything in `outcomes` is actually defined functions,however in the question there were also strings in `outcomes` as well.

Comment: @timmy it's extremely easy to handle constants - lambda functions. See the default get result above.

Comment: that makes it more understandable ,and ready for future edits